# segmentation fault en lista doble enlazada en la funcion ordenar

Tags: c

Necesito hacer un intercambio de punteros, es decir, en la función `ordenar`.

Para ello me dispuse a analizar los 3 casos por ejemplos.

En el caso de que la lista tenga 3 o mas elementos y la posicion del nodo sea la inicial, entonces preguntaré si el dato, en este caso `chart`, es mayor al que le sigue. Si es así entonces los intercambiaré de posición. Para ello guardo los punteros en `*p1` hasta `*p5` y luego les asigno esos punteros al nodo con la letra mayor para moverla así a la siguiente posición. Algo parecido al método burbuja pero con nodos y punteros en vez de mover los datos.

```
void ordenar(nodo_l *&cab){

    nodo_l *r=cab ;
    nodo_l *j=cab;
    nodo_l *p1,*p2,*p3,*p4,*p5;
    char *guar= (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    while(r!=NULL){

        if(j->ant==NULL && j->sig == NULL){
            printf("que vas a ordenar si solo tienes un dato!!\n");
        }else{

            if(j->ant == NULL && j->sig !=NULL){
                if(j->dato[1] > j->sig->dato[1]){
                    p1=j->sig;
                    p2=j->ant;
                    p3=j->sig->ant;
                    p4=j->sig->sig;
                    p5=j->sig->sig->ant;

                    j->sig=p4;
                    j->ant=p3;
                    j->sig->ant=p5;
                    j->ant->ant=p2;
                    j->ant->sig=p1; //aqui segmentation fault
                }
            }

            if(j->ant !=NULL && j->ant != NULL){
                printf("aqui estoy en la posicion nodo medio\n");
            }
            if(j->ant!=NULL && j->sig == NULL){
                printf("aqui estoy en la posicion nodo ultimo\n");
            }
        }

        r=r->sig;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Te estás liando con tanto puntero:

Supongamos la siguiente lista:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
     ^
     j
```

Vamos a ver lo que almacenas en los punteros:

```
p1 -> C
p2 -> A
p3 -> B
p4 -> D
p5 -> C
```

Es decir, los punteros p3 y p5 no tienen demasiado sentido:

- `p3` apunta al mismo nodo que `j`
- `p5` apunta al mismo nodo que `p1`

Esto en sí mismo no ocasiona problemas, pero complica el código y dificulta la tarea de localiar el error real. Vamos a simplificar un poco el ćodigo:

```
nodo_l *p1,*p2,*p4;
p1=j->sig;
p2=j->ant;
// p3=j->sig->ant;
p4=j->sig->sig;
// p5=j->sig->sig->ant;

j->sig=p4;
j->ant=p3; // Error de compilacion
j->sig->ant=p5; 
j->ant->ant=p2;
j->ant->sig=p1; //aqui segmentation fault
```

La línea comentada da un error de compilación... si la analizamos un poco vemos que, tal y como hemos dicho antes, `p3` apunta al nodo `j`, luego en esa línea estaríamos haciendo lo siguiente:

```
j->ant = j
```

Lo cual no tiene demasiado sentido ya que nos estamos cargando la lista enlazada.

Ya hemos localizado un error, pero hay más... vamos a revisar los condicionales:

```
if(j->ant == NULL && j->sig !=NULL){
//        ^^
```

Es decir, el código se ejecutará si `j->ant` **apunta a 0**, es decir, cuando `j` sea el primer nodo de la lista. Si estamos ante el primer nodo está claro que `p2` va a ser `NULL`. Otro puntero que podemos retirar de la lista...

El caso es que usar nombres tan genéricos `p1`, `p2`, ... genera un código confuso y dificil de leer... lo único que quieres es colocar desplazar el nodo `j` una posición. Para ello hay que intercambiar las posiciones de `j` y de `j->sig`. Como estamos al principio de la lista implica tocar 5 punteros:

```
      |   |-sig-> |   |-sig-> |   |          |   |-sig-> |   |-sig-> |   |
      | A |       | B |       | C | =>       | B |       | A |       | C |
<-ant-|   | <-ant-|   | <-ant-|   |    <-ant-|   | <-ant-|   | <-ant-|   |
```

Es decir:

```
nodo_l * nodoA = j;
nodo_l * nodoB = j->sig;
nodo_l * nodoC = j->sig->sig;

nodoB->ant = NULL;
nodoB->sig = nodoA; 
nodoC->ant = nodoA;

nodoA->sig=nodoC;
j->ant=b;
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, lo implementare haber si soluciona mi problema , en terminos generales necesitaba realizar  una funcion que ordene una lista enlazada ya creada es decir no quiero ordenarla a medida que se insertan letras. podria decir que un metodo burbuja aplicado a nodos.